# Could the gnatho/idiosoma exist in a large animal?

Tags: creature-design, anatomy

The gnathosoma and idiosoma are peculiar body sections that define mites and ticks. Unlike almost all other animals, with at least some measure of a head, these members divide the body into the gnathosoma at the front for consumption, and the idiosoma which takes on every other function

While this first seems like a good division for truly alien creatures, there are some issues that may exist in this form. Specifically, size: The largest animal divided in this way is no more than a centimeter long, and less than a quarter the size of even the shortest human nerves. At these sizes, the lack of a head should have a negligible effect on the body's function. However, on the scales of a potentially sapient species, the head seems much more important for useful reaction times

Could a large being have this arrangement of structures, or would the lack of the head be too detrimental?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there's an actual brain, it doesn't seem it would make that much difference where in the body it's located.  There are annelids (segmented worms like earthworms) that have effectively equal "brains" in each segment; there were dinosaurs (generically speaking) that literally had bigger "brains" near their pelvis than in their head.  An octopus has a three-lobed brain wrapped around its digestive tract.

I think you'd have a hard time making the case that having the brain as non-centrally located as possible, and running most of its inputs and nearly all of its outputs through a separate structure (the spinal cord) improves reaction times; it seems to me that a centralized brain, directly "wired" to everything, would do at least as well (and be better protected).

Comment: I'm in agreement, generally. I would want to point out that if high-bandwidith sensory organs develop, these will tend to gravitate towards that brain which could be a weird look if the gnathosoma isn't nearby.

Comment: @JohnO Pierson's Puppeteer weird enough?

Comment: Niven's an engineer by trade, I don't think it's possible for him to imagine things that he designs can't work in biology. Besides, didn't they have a hand/mouth near each eyeball?

Comment: @JohnO Each "head" was a hand/ear/mouth/eye on a stalk like a goose neck.  The nerve in that neck must have been as big as a bird's spinal cord -- combined optic nerve, brachial nerve/artery/vein, and still an airway and esophagus.  Yes, I also remember wondering how a Kzin could even breathe, never mind move like a predator, with that gridwork of rib cage...